# How to compute $\int_0^1 x^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am working on the following calculus problem. Would you guys help me how to integrate the following function:

$$
\int^1_0 x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2\right)dx
$$

I was struggling to compute this. I really appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: There isn't a nice, closed form solution for this unfortunately. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x%5E2*sin%28pi%2F2*x%5E2%29+from+0+to+1) is what Wolfram Alpha gives. It might seem like this is a solution, but the Fresnel integral is more or less defined to be what you have written so it's like saying the solution to the integral is the integral, in a matter of speaking. To get an approximate value, you have to do a quadrature on your integral.

Comment: Are you sure it should be $x^2$ and not $x$ in front of the sine argument? Eg $x \sin (\pi x^2 / 2)$ ? This makes the integral doable

Answer (score 1):

[image]
A plot of the Fresnel Integral. The value of your integral seems to be the value of the first maxima divided by $\pi$ .

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem numerically and got approximately $I=5.5 \times 10^{-3}$. I'm trying to solve it by calculus.

Comment: I have the feeling should have been a comment.